# FlashBuilder started going REALLY slow. Also, profiler doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash

I've got a Flash project that was occasionally freezing, then after a few seconds catching back up. I figured it was probably just spending too much time processing unnecessary data, so I wanted to look under the hood and see what was going on.

I popped open my project in Flash Builder, hit "Profile ", then the project launched… and nothing else happened. I stared at it for a while wondering where the profiler was. No dialog opened up with profiler options or anything. After 60 seconds I got an error. I wish I could reproduce this error again now, but it was along the lines of "Unable to connect to the profiler after 60 seconds."

Google'd around and no one could really help. Debugging was already enabled, I'm using the debug flash player, all the project configuration was correct… I tried right-clicking the video while it was playing and clicking "Debugger" to manually connect to the profiler, however when I tried this it just said "A connection to the debugger or profiler could not be established". I tried connecting with the IP and port, as well, but no luck.

So I gave up and decided to just insert several `trace()` statements to figure out where I was getting lost. After adding a few I hit Run and nothing happened… I waited for a bit then hit Run again. Still nothing. I walked away to get a drink, came back, and my browser was open to a blank page. No project. I tried right-clicking and the right-click menu wouldn't open. I closed the browser, removed all the `trace()` statements, then before I could click run the right-click menu popped up… It was the Flash Player menu even though the browser was now closed and I was in Flash Builder.

I cleaned the project, tried Run again, it took FIFTEEN MINUTES for my project to display in the browser. (It used to take just seconds)

I tried restarting my computer but that didn't fix it. I tried rolling back to an old git commit in case something changed in the project settings but that didn't fix it.

When I go to other sites Flash loads just fine. When I compile a build release and open this in my browser it loads just fine. But when I try to open the development release it all but crashes my machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After paying to speak with a Flash consultant, I've been informed that Flash just doesn't play nicely with profilers. When I informed him that I tried to plug in a profiler he laughed and said "Crashed, didn't it?"

Although not an ideal response, the only safe way to trace execution in Flash is the old fashioned way - lots of `trace()` statements and break points.

As for fixing the really slow playback, I resolved it by re-installing Flash Player.